# How do I get this variable to work right in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a dice game but I'm having problems with my dice variables and keeping track of the score for the current round.

Basically, there are four dice, and the round score is the total of the dice added together (you have a certain amount of rerolls per round).

But when I try to use the game, the round score is only showing one die's number, whichever one was most recently rolled (clicked).

Here is my code:

```
namespace DiceGame
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int die1;
    int die2;
    int die3;
    int die4;
    int rollsRemaining = 6;
    int scoreRound;
    int scoreTotal;
    int numberRound;
    Random random;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random random = new Random();

        int die1 = random.Next(1, 7);
        int die2 = random.Next(1, 7);
        int die3 = random.Next(1, 7);
        int die4 = random.Next(1, 7);

        dieOne.Content = die1;
        dieTwo.Content = die2;
        dieThree.Content = die3;
        dieFour.Content = die4;

        int scoreRound = die1 + die2 + die3 + die4;
        roundScore.Text = "Round Score: " + scoreRound;
    }

    private void dieOne_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        if (rollsRemaining != 0)
        {
            int die1 = random.Next(1, 7);
            dieOne.Content = die1;
            rollsRemaining = rollsRemaining - 1;
            string string1 = rollsRemaining.ToString();
            rollsLeft.Text = "Rolls Left: " + string1;
            roundScore.Text = "Round Score: " + (die1 + die2 + die3 +die4);
        }
        else
        { }
    }

    private void dieTwo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        if (rollsRemaining != 0)
        {
            int die2 = random.Next(1, 7);
            dieTwo.Content = die2;
            rollsRemaining = rollsRemaining - 1;
            string string1 = rollsRemaining.ToString();
            rollsLeft.Text = "Rolls Left: " + string1;
            roundScore.Text = "Round Score: " + (die1 + die2 + die3 + die4);
        }
        else
        { }
    }

    private void dieThree_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        if (rollsRemaining != 0)
        {
            int die3 = random.Next(1, 7);
            dieThree.Content = die3;
            rollsRemaining = rollsRemaining - 1;
            string string1 = rollsRemaining.ToString();
            rollsLeft.Text = "Rolls Left: " + string1;
            roundScore.Text = "Round Score: " + (die1 + die2 + die3 + die4);
        }
        else
        { }
    }

    private void dieFour_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        if (rollsRemaining != 0)
        {
            int die4 = random.Next(1, 7);
            dieFour.Content = die4;
            rollsRemaining = rollsRemaining - 1;
            string string1 = rollsRemaining.ToString();
            rollsLeft.Text = "Rolls Left: " + string1;
            roundScore.Text = "Round Score: " + (die1 + die2 + die3 + die4);
        }
        else
        { }
    }

    private void newRound_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        scoreTotal = scoreTotal + scoreRound;
        totalScore.Text = "Total Score: " + scoreTotal;
        rollsRemaining = 6;
        rollsLeft.Text = "Rolls Left: " + rollsRemaining;
        scoreRound = 0;
        roundScore.Text = "Round Score: " + scoreRound;

        Random random = new Random();

        int die1 = random.Next(1, 7);
        int die2 = random.Next(1, 7);
        int die3 = random.Next(1, 7);
        int die4 = random.Next(1, 7);

        dieOne.Content = die1;
        dieTwo.Content = die2;
        dieThree.Content = die3;
        dieFour.Content = die4;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing code; but that is *way* too much. You need to use a debugger to narrow your question down so its more specific than "what is wrong with this code?"

Comment: Just a small suggestion - you should only make one instance of `Random`.

Answer (score 2):

you have local variables for the dices in your methods (die1, die2...) and also class data members with the same names (die1, die2...)

when you use a variable, first the compiler looks in the current scope (here it's your method) and only then searches in the outer scope (the class).

you initialized the numbers in the scope of the constructure with local variables so the data members are still 0.

when clicking a button you set another local variable (say die1) with a value and then add it up with the rest. so now die1 (the local) is added with die2,3,4 the data members (and they are 0). so you get just die1. same in the other buttons.

learn more about scopes here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

just for this case - remove the local variables and use only the data members.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Random random = new Random();

    die1 = random.Next(1, 7);
    die2 = random.Next(1, 7);
    die3 = random.Next(1, 7);
    die4 = random.Next(1, 7);

    //...
}
```

And similarily in `newRound_Click`

Comment: You're right with this, but a bit confusing with saying "data members". I think it would be useful to call them class-level variables versus local variables.

Comment: class-level variables versus local variables or else we could say fields vs local variables